# Como puedo tomar valores de un insert con un trigger ? Sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, datatables

Tengo una duda, busco poder evaluar los datos de un INSERT con un trigger en tabla.
Cuando haga un insert disparar el trigger evalúe los datos y haga un UPDATE en una 2da tabla tomando un valor del primer INSERT.

Es posible hacer esto O algun método para lograrlo?

Saludos.

Comment: Claro que sí, justamente esa es la idea de un trigger, ahora bien, si quieres una respuesta más acabada, te sugiero que agregues a tu pregunta 1) Ejemplo de las tablas en cuestión 2) lo que hubieras investigado/intentado  hasta ahora, de esta forma tu pregunta será mejor recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que pides, tienes un par de tablas virtuales llamadas `inserted` y `deleted`. Esas tablas tienen la misma estructura que la tabla a la que pertenece el trigger con los datos después de la operación y antes de la operación. En un `INSERT`, la tabla `deleted` estará vacía, en un `UPDATE` ambas tablas tendrán datos, mientras que en `DELETE` estará vacía la tabla `inserted`.

Dejo un ejemplo genérico de lo que pides.

```
CREATE TABLE Ejemplo(
    ID       int,
    Columna1 varchar(100)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE OtraTabla(
    ID       int,
    ColumnaX varchar(100)
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TI_Ejemplo ON Ejemplo
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE ot SET
        ColumnaX = Columna1
    FROM OtraTabla ot
    JOIN inserted  i  ON ot.ID = i.ID;

END

GO
DROP TABLE Ejemplo, OtraTabla
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, un par de ajustes y entro como anillo al dedo este trigger.